# Copy Constructor Big 3 C++ issue

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, destructor, copy-constructor

I am struggling with implementing big 3 idea (assignment operator overload, copy constructor, destructor).  my code below will crash the program.  It compiles so I cannot even see any error hint. Please help.

```
enter code here

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include<sstream>


class TwoD
{
private:
int MaxRows;
int MaxCols;
double** outerArray;

public:
TwoD(int maxRows, int maxCols)
{
    MaxRows = maxRows;
    MaxCols = maxCols;
    outerArray = new double *[MaxRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxRows; i++)
        outerArray[i] = new double[MaxCols];
}

TwoD(const TwoD& rightside)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < MaxRows; l++)  
        for (int m = 0; m < MaxCols; m++)
            outerArray[l][m] = rightside.outerArray[l][m];    
}

void input()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < MaxRows; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < MaxCols; j++)
            cin >> outerArray[k][j];
}

void outPut()
{
    for (int l = 0; l < MaxRows; l++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < MaxCols; m++)
            cout << outerArray[l][m] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

const TwoD& operator =(const TwoD& rightSide)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < MaxRows; l++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < MaxCols; m++)
            outerArray[l][m] = rightSide.outerArray[l][m];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return *this;
}



const TwoD operator + (const TwoD& rightSide)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < MaxRows; l++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < MaxCols; m++)
            outerArray[l][m] = outerArray[l][m] + rightSide.outerArray[l][m];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return *this;
}

~TwoD()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxRows; i++)
        delete[] outerArray[i];
    delete[] outerArray;
}

};

int main()
{
TwoD example1(3, 3), example2(3,3), example3(3,3);
cout << "input example1" << endl;
example1.input();
example1.outPut();

cout << "input example2" << endl;
example2.input();
example2.outPut();

cout << "combining the two is" << endl;
example3 = example1 + example2;
example3.outPut();


return 0;
}
```

changed copy constructor

```
TwoD(const TwoD& rightside): MaxRows(rightside.MaxRows), MaxCols(rightside.MaxCols)
{
    outerArray = new double *[MaxRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxRows; i++)
        outerArray[i] = new double[MaxCols];

    for (int l = 0; l < MaxRows; l++)  
        for (int m = 0; m < MaxCols; m++)
            outerArray[l][m] = rightside.outerArray[l][m];    
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? Which output lines do you see?

Comment: It let me enter the example1 and example2,  By the time it tries to add it.  It crashes without any hint or error message.

Comment: Something to put you on track : in your copy constructor, when you do  outerArray[l][m] = rightside.outerArray[l][m]; , where do you think outerArray is allocated ?

Comment: I would think the calling object (left side of "=")'s private variable (array) should be updated.

Comment: I added this to the copy constructor.  It appears to be working (no crash) Is this what you meant?  It certainly does not look elegant algorithmically.  Do you have any better suggestion?.  Please see the end of the original code posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your copy constructor fails to allocate memory for the matrix.
2. Your copy assignment operator and `operator+()` fail to account for the possibility that `*this` and `rightSide` have different dimensions.

Comment: I guess I am not fully understanding *this.  Could you please provide some more help?  what part of code can be changed how?

Comment: Do I need to put another destructor within copy constructor?

Comment: Could you please take a look at my updated code above?  It is working, but do I need to update operator = over loader with the same concept as well (in order to be correct)

Comment: @UjaeKang: The assignment *should* check that the array dimensions match, and either reallocate or report an error if they don't. It doesn't need to allocate anything if they do match: the memory was already allocated in the constructor. And, as the answer says, `operator+` (which is actually a misnamed `operator+=`) should also check.

Comment: Your copy constructor will leak memory if outerarray has already been allocated. And yes, operator+ should also allocate memory if it has not been allocated already. But before the memory is allocated, you should free any previously allocated memory.

Comment: @IanThompson: `outerArray` hasn't already been allocated in the copy constructor, since the objects hasn't been constructed yet.

Comment: I got it.  I appreciate your help again Mike!

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, sorry, I meant the operator= not the copy constructor.